# Error while instaling Padre 1.0 on Windows, Strawberry Perl v5.20, how find root cause?

Tags: windows, perl, testing, padre, dmake

I'm trying create DWIM for Windows perl v5.20
So I install all depenencies for Padre 1.0
[Padre-ide github repo](https://github.com/mishin/Padre-ide),
[dwimperl-windows](https://github.com/mishin/dwimperl-windows)

and I have errors in dmake test

[padre_log_2.txt](https://github.com/mishin/presentation/blob/master/padre_test/padre_log_2.txt)

Have you got any ideas how to repair it?

All errors make me confusing,
I couldn't imagine how start debug padre to find core of error (root cause)

even for first error

```
t/02_new.t ................. 1/62 # Looks like you planned 62 tests but ran 1.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 just after 1.
```

or second

```
t/05_project.t ............. 1/16 Invalid version format (non-numeric data) at C
:\Users\TOSH\Documents\GitHub\padre-mi\blib\lib/Padre/Wx/Menu/Debug.pm line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Users\TOSH\Documents\GitHub\padre-mi\blib\lib/Padre/Wx/Menu/Debug.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at C:\Users\TOSH\Documents\GitHub\padre-mi\blib\lib/Padre/Wx/Menubar.pm line 72.
# Looks like you planned 16 tests but ran 2.
```

well, I try the same thing with [Padre 0.94](https://github.com/mishin/padre-0.94)
here [build.log](https://github.com/mishin/padre-0.94/blob/master/build.log)

error is more interesting
[Possible precedence issue with control flow operator at](https://github.com/mishin/padre-0.94/blob/master/build.log#L518)

[01_dmake_test.log](https://github.com/mishin/padre-0.94/blob/master/01_dmake_test.log)

I start debug step by step

```
perl -Ilib -MCarp::Always -e "use Test::More;use_ok('Padre::Config');done_testing()" > error.log 2>&1
```

and I got

```
Error:  Failed to find share dir for dist 'Padre' at C:/Users/TOSH/Documents/GitHub/dwimperl-windows/strawberry-perl-5.20.0.1-32bit-portable/perl/vendor/lib/File/ShareDir.pm line 173.
```

see 
[error.log](https://github.com/mishin/padre-0.94/blob/master/error.log)
[01_padre_debug.pl](https://github.com/mishin/padre-0.94/blob/master/01_padre_debug.pl)

Comment: So what's in `blib\lib/Padre/Wx/Menu/Debug.pm` line 5?

Comment: https://github.com/mishin/Padre-ide/blob/master/lib/Padre/Wx/Menu/Debug.pm#L5 use 5.008;

Comment: https://github.com/mishin/Padre-ide/blob/master/blib/lib/Padre/Wx/Menu/Debug.pm#L5 use 5.008;

Comment: [Menubar.pm](https://github.com/mishin/Padre-ide/blob/master/blib/lib/Padre/Wx/Menubar.pm#L72)  `require Padre::Wx::Menu::Debug;`

Comment: Sounds like your Perl build is bonkers. Do you get an error from the following: `perl -e"use 5.008;"` You could try upgrading `version`

Comment: I'd also make sure that `blib\lib/Padre/Wx/Menu/Debug.pm` uses Windows line endings.

Comment: cpanm version <new line>
version is up to date. (0.9912)

Comment: `perl -e"use 5.008;"` works fine

Comment: [Wx/Menu/Debug.pm](https://github.com/mishin/Padre-ide/blob/master/lib/Padre/Wx/Menu/Debug.pm) has only LF ending

Answer (score 1):

I would re-install DWIM as described below:

1. Download DWIM from [here](http://dwimperl.com/windows.html)
2. Install DWIM into C:\DWIMPerl_5.14.2 and test installation.  Then start Padre

[image]

3. Padre up and running

[image]

This was done successfully on Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: it's very good, but I try to create DWIM myself with perl v5.20 and I got any error messages which I cannot repair, I try dwim v5.14 too and it's work for me, but I want more modern perl version and more modern padre version, I prefer v5.20

Comment: Good deal.  You may wish to contact Gabor Szabo, the maintainer of DWIM Perl, for assistance.

Comment: I also tried Strawberry Perl 5.20.x 32-bit and 64-bit and was having issues with dependent modules like Alien::wxWidgets not compiling.  I think it is commonplace that the DWIM distribution is usually behind a version or more when it comes to Perl, Padre, etc.

Comment: Gabor says, that I have not touched Padre for a long time. Maybe someone on the Padre mailing list, or on PerlMonks or on Stack Overflow will have some ideas.

Comment: See here for a discussion on PerlMonks  (http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1106777)

Comment: thanks, interesting communications, good advice - install padre and then upgrade perl? How, I don't know. Replace binary perl.exe?

Comment: Install latest version of Perl in a different folder and use that version of Perl as your default Perl.  Be sure to change %PATH% to see newest Perl first.

Comment: yes, it's good case, but I still want to install padre under v5.20,   I hope I can do it

Comment: Once you install Perl 5.20.x in the new folder, install or build Padre in that same Perl environment.